# Sql Server Full Text Search one table for text values in another table

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Is it possible to run a full text search on an FTS-indexed column for all values in another table?

Conceptually it'd look like

`select d.* from Docs d, Tags t where CONTAINS(d.fulltext, t.tagvalue)`

I'm rather new to MSSQL FTS, though I know that the equivalent would work in postgres

`select d.* from docs d, tags t where to_tsquery(t.tagvalue) @@ to_tsvector(d.fulltext)`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not directly.  You would have to build dynamic SQL strings, one row for every join set (pair of Docs and Tags rows), and then execute those strings.  That's probably not practical.

In the FROM query, if you had 1,000 records in Docs and 1,000 records in Tags, the result set would have 1,000,000 rows.  I'm assuming you knew that and just dummied up some quick T-SQL - obviously this wouldn't work in production.

Comment: thanks. Indeed, this was just a q&d query and not even really in the domain of what I'm hoping to achieve. However, if I understand your response, it is that this isn't really a feasible implementation. Is that correct?

Comment: @swasheck Yep, I wouldn't try to implement something like that in production.